# Why doesn't Haskell report a mismatch with 1 = 2?

Tags: haskell, erlang, pattern-matching, elixir

I'm confused by Haskell's pattern matching behavior. If I match 1 against 2 in either Erlang or Elixir, I expect and get a match error message. In Haskell, ghci just silently accepts the match attempt.

With Erlang in erl:

```
2> 1 = 2.
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 2
```

With Elixir in iex:

```
iex(1)> 1 = 2
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 2
```

However, with Haskell in ghci:

```
Prelude> 1 = 2
Prelude>
```

Can someone explain why Haskell doesn't report a match error?

Comment: In brief: it is a corner case of pattern matching, which presumably wasn't considered problematic enough to be ruled out. Feel free to ask for further clarification if the answers to the suggested question still leave you with lingering questions about it.

Comment: It’s because of lazy evaluation. A pattern match like that is not checked until you use one of the variables in the pattern.